# ggplot2 group and sort for stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

I have following dataset, I would like to get a stacked bar chart sorted by group using ggplot2 in `R`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)


dat=read.csv(textConnection(
  "Category,Value1,Value2,Total,Group
A,10,10,20,1
B,20,30,50,1
C,5,2,7,1
D,5,10,15,2
E,10,20,30,2
F,30,4,34,2"))

dfm <- melt(dat,id.vars = c(1,5)) %>% filter(variable %in% c("Value1","Value2"))


ggplot(dfm, aes(reorder(Category ,value), value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col() +coord_flip()+theme_bw() +geom_text(aes(label = value),position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),size=3)
```

Desired output:

[image]

However when I run the above ggplot2 I get the following output. I'm unable to sort by group.

[image]

How do I sort by Total, and also by group?

1. How do I sort by Total (sum of value 1 and value 2), and also by group?
2. How do we display total on the right for stacked bar chart?

Comment: I don't understand the logic used to reach the order BACDEF.

Comment: I need the data sorted by “ Group” Variable.  That’s why group 1 has BAC and group 2 had DEF.

Comment: For question 1, you could do something like ‘dfm |> add_count(Category, wt = Value, name = Total) |> arrange(Group, -Total) |> mutate(Category = fct_inorder(Category))’ and feed that into your plot. That will make Category into an ordered factor ordered by group and then total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  arrange(desc(Group), Total) %>%
  mutate(Category = fct_inorder(Category)) %>%
  pivot_longer(Value1:Total) -> dat2
  
ggplot(filter(dat2, name != "Total"),
         aes(value, Category, label = value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = name), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5, reverse = TRUE))  +
  geom_text(data = filter(dat2, name == "Total"),
            hjust = -0.5)
```

[image]